# QT: Using the mouse wheel when dragging from outside of application

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QT application with a TreeView in which items can be dragged into and around the TreeView. The Scroll wheel is able to scroll up and down the view when collapsed sufficiently to show the scroll bar in all cases except for when dragging in an item from the desktop.

Could anyone point me in the right directon? Or inform me on what questions I should be asking?

Answer (score 0):

is the problem maybe related to the application not beeing in focus anymore? Keypresses (also mousewheel scroll) is usually send to the application which is activ/in focus.

I have done an private project which would react to keypresses on OS (windows) level to be able to control it while the user would play a computer game.

I don't have enough reputation to make a comment. Hope this might help you.